# JAVA return value from constructor

Tags: java, return-value, boolean-expression

```
public class RightAngleTriangle
{
    int height;
    int width;
    double area;
    double perimeter;

    public RightAngleTriangle()
    {
        height = 1;
        width = 1;
    }

    public RightAngleTriangle(int hei, int wid)
    {
        if(hei > 0 && wid > 0)
        {
            height = hei;
            width = wid;
        }
        else
        {
            height = 1;
            width = 1;
        }
    }

    public double area()
    {
        area = height * width;
        return area;
    }

    public double perimeter()
    {
        perimeter = (height * 2) + (width * 2);
        return perimeter;
    }

    public boolean isIsosceles()
    {
        if(height == width)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean largerThan(RightAngleTriangle anotherRightAngleTriangle)
    {
        if (area(RightAngleTriangle) > area(anotherRightAngleTriangle))
        {

        }
    }

}
```

For the method `largerThan()` how can I make it so `largerThan()` returns `true` if and only if the area of this `RightAngleTriangle` is larger than the area of `anotherRightAngleTriangle`. I am not sure how to compare the areas because the `area` is calculated locally. I tried initializing `area` globally but I need the returned value not the initialized value.

Comment: `largerThan()` ain't no constructor.

Comment: whoops, I meant method

Comment: Use "this" to refer to the class using the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a comment `largerThan()` is not a constructor, is a method

now to your question

you need to call the method in the current instance and in the object passed as parameter

```
public boolean largerThan(RightAngleTriangle anotherRightAngleTriangle)
{
    if (this.area() > anotherRightAngleTriangle.area( ))
    {
         //your logic
    }
}
```

or simple doing

```
public boolean largerThan(RightAngleTriangle anotherRightAngleTriangle)
{
   return this.area() > anotherRightAngleTriangle.area();
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but why is it `this.area()` instead of `RightAngleTriangle.area()`?

Comment: @sdfjbs Because area() is not a static method. Only static methods can be called like that (ClassName.staticMethod()). A non static method can only be called from an object of that class and "this" simply refers to the current object you are operating in.

Comment: @sdfjbs you just cant do **RightAngleTriangle.area()** because the method area is not static...

Comment: Then how come you can do `anotherRightAngleTriangle.area( )`?

Comment: **anotherRightAngleTriangle** is a variable of the class, totally different thing